# Image being cropped in outlook

Tags: image, outlook

I've been absolutely fog-washed by this issue on an eDM I'm trying to debug. I can't get to the guy who built unfortunately so hopefully you masters can aid me.

[image: Broken/Cropped image outlook]

This is what I'm getting and this is the code.

```
<tr>
 <td width="100%"  height="auto" class="rightColumnContent1" style="padding: 0 8px 8px; line-height:17px;" align="left"><a style="display:block; line-height:100%; " href="#">
  <img     src="http://careers.telstra.com/TelstraCareers/media/edm/campaign/pb/video.jpg" style="max-width: 480px !important; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; display:block; width: 100% !important; border: 0;" class="columnImage1" mc:label="right_column_image" mc:edit="right_column_image" /> </a>  </td>     </tr>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: It was the length of the main body cutting the image by the way. I fixed this by restricting the height of the content box the image was in. Seemed to fix it!

Comment: You should add that as an answer for people who have the same problem. In fact, you should mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was the length of the main body cutting the image by the way. I fixed this by restricting the height of the content box the image was in. Seemed to fix it!